# SQL Case statement error Msg 8114

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Trying to build a simple case statement using SQL Server 2008 and running across an issue giving me the following error message:

`Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 6
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.`

I've isolated the script causing the issue to the following:

```
CASE WHEN tPersonLocationHist.LocationCode = 'DC' 
        AND (tPersonJobHist.FullTimeEquivalent = 1) 
        AND (MONTH(tPersonStatusHist.LatestHireDate) < 10) 
        THEN tPersonStatusHist.NormalHoursPerWeek / 5
```

The tPersonStatusHist.NormalHoursPerWeek is formatted as decimal; however, I can't get it to calculate.

Any tips? The resulting calculation needs to be in decimal form (to two decimal digits).

Even if I change the THEN statement to just '7.5', it then returns:

`Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '7.5' to data type int.`

I've tried using `CONVERT(decimal(4,2),tPersonJobHist.NormalHoursPerWeek * 7.5)`, but no luck on that either.

Only thing that's working is to do it as: 
`CONVERT(int,tPersonJobHist.NormalHoursPerWeek * 7.5)`, but then it is dropping the decimals and just giving the whole integer.

As you can probably tell, I'm new into SQL and still learning the rope, so any help you can give is much appreciated.

Comment: What is the datatype of `NormalHoursPerWeek`?

Comment: Please read through this blog I wrote:  http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/MSSQLServer/sql-server-case-when-data-type-problems

Comment: Datatype is shrsDecimal4

Most of my other THEN statements are returning a defined result (i.e. '0' or '8'). I only have a couple of pieces that require a calculation... do I need to do separate CASE statements for the calculation ones?

Answer (score 0):

Are your other cases/else returning varchar? They should all return the same datatype. You may want to cast/convert them to be sure.

```
CAST(CONVERT(decimal(4,2),tPersonJobHist.NormalHoursPerWeek * 7.5) AS varchar(50))
```

Comment: I tried this answer and received the following error message:
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 8, Line 6
Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.

Comment: You could be going past 99.99, so you might try `decimal(13,2)` or something large that wouldn't overflow on the data. Also, your other `case`s and `else` should be checked for similar problems, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

First convert to decimal then do the division:

`THEN CONVERT(decimal(4,2), tPersonStatusHist.NormalHoursPerWeek) / 5`

Or cast is an option:

`THEN CAST(tPersonStatusHist.NormalHoursPerWeek AS decimal(4,2)) / 5`